# Cannot install kubelet, Kubeadm, etc

Tags: kubernetes

In a nutshell, I munged my `kubeadm` cluster and am trying to start from scratch (I was not able to do a proper tear down of the cluster, which is why I was forced to go this route of `kubeadm reset` and `sudo yum remove kubeadm kubectl kubelet kubernetes-cni kube*` minus the removal of the node from the cluster).

I removed all packages (running on RHEL 7) and am now trying to reinstall, but getting the error on startup:

```
-- Unit kubelet.service has begun starting up.
Nov 13 12:23:50 thalia2.ahc.umn.edu kubelet[31361]: F1113 12:23:50.681719   31361 server.go:190] failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error failed to
read kubelet config file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml", error: open /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml: no such file or directory
Nov 13 12:23:50 thalia2.ahc.umn.edu systemd[1]: kubelet.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Nov 13 12:23:50 thalia2.ahc.umn.edu systemd[1]: Unit kubelet.service entered failed state.
Nov 13 12:23:50 thalia2.ahc.umn.edu systemd[1]: kubelet.service failed.
Nov 13 12:24:00 thalia2.ahc.umn.edu systemd[1]: kubelet.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 13 12:24:00 thalia2.ahc.umn.edu systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
-- Subject: Unit kubelet.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit kubelet.service has finished starting up.
--
```

Every post I've seen regarding this error indicates that this file (`/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml`) is missing because I did not run `kubeadm init`, but I am NOT creating a master node - I  just want to run this like it was a fresh install as per [installing-kubeadm-kubelet-and-kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/#installing-kubeadm-kubelet-and-kubectl)

Am I missing something obvious? I do not remember running `kubeadm init` on each node before I started the `kubelet service` in my initial install a couple months back, plus, nowhere in the directions for installing the packages does it say to do a `Kubeadm init.`

Also of note: On my former master node, I am getting the error after trying a reinstall and start of `kubectl`:

```
Get https://134.84.53.162:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dthalia0.ahc.umn.edu&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 134.84.53.162:6443: connect: connection refused
Nov 13 13:40:40 thalia0.ahc.umn.edu kubelet[17689]: W1113 13:40:40.487124   17689 cni.go:188] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Nov 13 13:40:40 thalia0.ahc.umn.edu kubelet[17689]: E1113 13:40:40.487404   17689 kubelet.go:2167] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNot
Ready message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
```

but, I thought I had removed everything by doing a `kubeadm reset`?

I did delete the `calico` folder on my former master node (`sudo rm -rf /var/etcd/calico-data`), and then did a restart of kubectl and am getting this error now:

```
Nov 13 13:55:37 thalia0.ahc.umn.edu kubelet[29725]: E1113 13:55:37.447381   29725 kubelet.go:2236] node "thalia0.ahc.umn.edu" not found
Nov 13 13:55:37 thalia0.ahc.umn.edu kubelet[29725]: E1113 13:55:37.547732   29725 kubelet.go:2236] node "thalia0.ahc.umn.edu" not found
Nov 13 13:55:37 thalia0.ahc.umn.edu kubelet[29725]: E1113 13:55:37.648002   29725 kubelet.go:2236] node "thalia0.ahc.umn.edu" not found
Nov 13 13:55:37 thalia0.ahc.umn.edu kubelet[29725]: E1113 13:55:37.748219   29725 kubelet.go:2236] node "thalia0.ahc.umn.edu" not found
Nov 13 13:55:37 thalia0.ahc.umn.edu kubelet[29725]: E1113 13:55:37.849201   29725 kubelet.go:2236] node "thalia0.ahc.umn.edu" not found
Nov 13 13:55:37 thalia0.ahc.umn.edu kubelet[29725]: E1113 13:55:37.950018   29725 kubelet.go:2236] node "thalia0.ahc.umn.edu" not found
Nov 13 13:55:38 thalia0.ahc.umn.edu kubelet[29725]: E1113 13:55:38.050193   29725 kubelet.go:2236] node "thalia0.ahc.umn.edu" not found
Nov 13 13:55:38 thalia0.ahc.umn.edu kubelet[29725]: E1113 13:55:38.150479   29725 kubelet.go:2236] node "thalia0.ahc.umn.edu" not found
Nov 13 13:55:38 thalia0.ahc.umn.edu kubelet[29725]: I1113 13:55:38.173736   29725 kubelet_node_status.go:276] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Nov 13 13:55:38 thalia0.ahc.umn.edu kubelet[29725]: I1113 13:55:38.180154   29725 kubelet_node_status.go:70] Attempting to register node thalia0.ahc.umn.edu
```

So, it would appear that there is "residue" from my old cluster. Is there some hidden package out there that a `kubeadm reset` and a `sudo yum remove kubeadm kubectl kubelet kubernetes-cni kube*` did not delete?

Comment: Going to have our server ops people do a backup restore on all nodes. Hopefully this will resolve the initial issue that drove me to this madness in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The issue ended up being that the `/var` directory had gotten full. Cleaned it out and now everything starts as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought I had removed everything by doing a `kubeadm reset`?

regarding [to documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-reset/) it is not delete everything. it just reverse the changes, so where you delete the packages and just broke all paths, run `kubeadm init` to reinitialise cluster.